# Access user control elements from parent

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, parent

I am trying to change what is visible in my user control by checking some checkbox's in my form (the parent). I have tried changing it directly in the parent form and in a function on the child's side. From debug the property is being changed but then after the call the property seems to reset to the default value.

My code on the parent side

```
public partial class Program: DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm
{
    public Program()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public class GlobalVariables
    {
        public static string categoryID = "1";
        public static string currentPage = "Campus";
    }

    private void ribbonControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        RibbonControl ribbon = sender as RibbonControl;
        RibbonHitInfo hitInfo = ribbon.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
        if (hitInfo.HitTest == RibbonHitTest.PageHeader)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(hitInfo.Page.Name + "");
            pnlPanel.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
            if(hitInfo.Page.Name == "Campus")
            {
                var Campus = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Campus();
                pnlPanel.Panel2.Controls.Add(Campus);
                GlobalVariables.currentPage = "Campus";
            }
            else if (hitInfo.Page.Name == "Report")
            {
                var Report = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Report();
                pnlPanel.Panel2.Controls.Add(Report);
                GlobalVariables.currentPage = "Report";
            }
            else if (hitInfo.Page.Name == "Admin")
            {
                var Admin = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Admin();
                pnlPanel.Panel2.Controls.Add(Admin);
                GlobalVariables.currentPage = "Admin";
            }

        }
    }

    private void Program_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Campus = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Campus();
        pnlPanel.Panel2.Controls.Add(Campus);

        List<string> Category = GenerateCategory();

        for(int j = 0; j<= Category.Count(); j++)
        {
            krpList.Items.Add(Category[j + 1]);
            krpValue.Items.Add(Category[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }

public void krpList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedIndex = krpList.SelectedIndex;
            krpValue.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
            GlobalVariables.categoryID = krpValue.SelectedItem + "";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(krpValue.SelectedItem);
            Reset();  
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            var Campus = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Campus();
            pnlPanel.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
            pnlPanel.Panel2.Controls.Add(Campus);
        }

        private void chkDisplay_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string displayInfo = "";
            var Campus = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Campus();
            displayInfo = chkDisplay.Text;
            Campus.UpdateAudit(displayInfo);
            Campus.treeList1.ClearNodes();
        }


    }
}
```

User control code

```
public void UpdateAudit(string displayInfo) //Child Method
{
    treeList1.ClearNodes(); //Adjusting property on user control element
    treeList1.Columns[1].VisibleIndex = 1;
    treeList1.Columns[2].VisibleIndex = 2;
    //...more code similar to above 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what I suspect, the form you are showing and the form you are using are two different instances . Can you add the full code where you are written var Campus = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Campus(); .... I think it should be some event handler.

Comment: @Rabi Please find full code as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, here is the problem, you are using multiple instances of same form.
you should rather create a single instance and use it .

```
public partial class Program: DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm {

UserControl Campus = null;

 public Program()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         Campus  = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Campus();
    }

 private void Program_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // remove this object creation
 //var Campus = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Campus();

        pnlPanel.Panel2.Controls.Add(Campus);
   ... 
}

 public void Reset() {
  // remove this object creation
 //  var Campus = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Campus();
}


private void chkDisplay_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

 string displayInfo = "";
  // remove this object creation
 // var Campus = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Campus();
}

private void ribbonControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
     ...
   if(hitInfo.Page.Name == "Campus")
            {
                // remove this object creation
                //var Campus = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Campus();

    }
    ...
}
}
```

Comment: I don't entirely follow this suggestion. A variable of type var at the class level without being even declared as public will not work. Could you please expand on how your suggestion is supposed to work?

Comment: did you also remove the object creation here :  if(hitInfo.Page.Name == "Campus")
{ var Campus = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Campus();

Comment: Yes I removed all reference to the original Campus variable. This only stopped all code from working so the user control no longer refresh's as well using this code.

Comment: This solution is a simple one and should work, unless you have some other glitches inside the code.

Comment: I have managed to get it working with what you have said to a point. However I am unable to call the methods or controls on the Campus user control. I have most probably done something wrong somewhere. I am basically using Campus.[methodnamehere](); but it is unable to find the method. Any suggestions?